# What does maximum fuel per jump mean?

Tags: elite-dangerous

What does maximum fuel per jump mean? I don't know if higher or lower is better and how it affects the gameplay.

Maximum fuel per jump has stopped me from jumping to systems several times so I want to understand how it works.

Comment: I will. I currently cant because my phone is junk and PCs are being used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Higher is generally better, it increases distance of single jump by using more fuel (but fuel efficiency is decreasing if you use fuel up to the limit - the longer jump the more fuel is wasted).
The standard upper limit is 5 ton per jump. Engineers can increase it a little (e.g. 5.21 ton per jump).

If you manually select some distant system in the galactic map (without building a route to it) and try to jump, you will receive the error about exceeding fuel-per-jump limit if the system is too far way. This can happen even if you have a route built - if you selected another system after route was built. You can assign a shortcut to ~"Select next nav system" and use it to re-select next-in-route system.

In general, economic jumps are short jumps, fuel efficiency is decreasing if you jump at biggest possible distance.
Scenario when higher limit is worse is when you may need to re-fuel: if you build a multi-hop route which uses almost all your fuel (without re-fuel) with 5 ton-per-jump limit. Having bigger per jump limit means that you can make one jump less, but you will need to re-fuel due to less fuel efficiency of long jumps.

Comment: This is very nice to know and understand. Thanks for your time spent in making answer.

Comment: I dont like it but without of it game makes no sense. You could just jump insanely long if you fill modules with fuel tanks.

Comment: In principle, it is allowed by in-game rules - remember of how Colonia was created - players amasses a lot of fuel for Jaques Station and it (mis)jumped. So this is more of FSD engine limitation.

Comment: Here's another, very natural, way you might find yourself trying to jump beyond your fuel use limit: (1) Plot a course using "Fastest Route" or manually select a system that's at the extreme end of your single-jump range. (2) Increase cargo load before jumping, without re-plotting. (3) More fuel will be required to move the greater mass along the same distance, so your fuel use limit may be exceeded.